# how to Make whole page scrollable instead to GridView Builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and creating a screen with following code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper/ui/widgets/card_wallpaper.dart';

import '../../providers/anime_provider.dart';
import '../../models/wallpaper.dart';
import '../../providers/wallpaper_provider.dart';

class AnimeDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String id = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    final selectedAnime = Provider.of<AnimeProvider>(context).findById(id);
    final selectedWallPaper =Provider.of<WallpaperProvider>(context).getByAnime(id);
    final appBar = AppBar(
      leading: BackButton(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      title: Text(
        selectedAnime.title,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          fontFamily: 'Righteous',
        ),
      ),
    );
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final double totalHeight = mediaQuery.size.height -appBar.preferredSize.height -mediaQuery.padding.top -335;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                child: Card(
                   elevation: 3.1,
                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                   ),
                   child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 300,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            child: Image.asset(
                                selectedAnime.imageUrl,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                       bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 25,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15, vertical: 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'WallPapers from ${selectedAnime.title}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Righteous',
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: totalHeight,
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 0.5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                value: selectedWallPaper[i],
                child: CardWallpaper(),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemCount: selectedWallPaper.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

When I run this app, the  `gridview` is scrollable but the image at the top of it does not scroll,but, I want to scroll whole page but only the grid scrolls even though I am using `singlechildscrollview`. I tried using expanded on gridview builder but it produces error.How can I make whole page scroll instead of just gridview.builder.
![See the screen here]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClDZy.jpg
As you can see when you scroll the page only gridview gets scrolled while top image remains there. I want to scroll the page as whole. Is there any way to determine the height of gridtile?

Answer (score 0):

In your gridview, set the parameter `scrollable: NeverScrollablePhysics()`.

Comment: adding `scrollable:NeverScrollablePhysics()` hides content inside gridview

Comment: I edited the question to make you question understandable